# How to set function execute order to using callback function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to handle functions execute order to using callbacks. Actually I'm learning Node.js. Because of its async, It's difficult to me to handle process. Anyway, There are 3 function that has callback,

```
function first(callback){
    console.log("First");
    callback;
}

function second(callback){
    console.log("Second");
    callback;
}


function third(callback){
    console.log("Third");
}

// Let's run it!

first(second(third));

// result 

Second
First
```

I don't understand why the result is. I expected below:

```
First
Second
Third
```

What's problem? How could I do it correctly? In Node.js, Do people usually handle functions excute order by using callbacks? that is little complex I think. Isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in other answers,

```
first(second(third));
```

this doesn't do what you think it does.

I think what you actually meant to do was this:

```
first(function(){
    second(function(){
        third(function(){
            // ...
        });
    });
});
```

In ES6 (Node 4+) syntax it'll be:

```
first(() => second(() => third()));
```

But what I prefer is an approach that uses Promises

```
function first(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        console.log("First");
        resolve();
    });
}

function second(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        console.log("Second");
        resolve();
    });
}

function third(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        console.log("Third");
        resolve();
    });
}
```

This gets rid of callbacks altogether, and makes more sense of the actual control flow:

```
first()
.then(second)
.then(third);
```

<sup>[checkout this article on promises](http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html)</sup>

And with the ES7 syntax (babel/typescript) it simply becomes:

```
async function first(){
    console.log("First");
}
// async function second...
// async function third...

await first();
await second();
await third();
```

<sup>[checkout this article on async/await](http://pouchdb.com/2015/03/05/taming-the-async-beast-with-es7.html)</sup>

Comment: The Promises solution isn't working for me, i'm scraping content and saving it in an array in function one and saving that array in a JSON file in function two but the array is getting stored firstthe empty array is getting saved first and then scraping is being done, can you sugest a better solution???

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have 2 functions, f and g

When you call `f(g())`

g() is evaluated first in order to provide the correct arguments for f()

so if you want to have f() executed first, and then the result passed to g as a parameter, you have to inverse the flow.

`g(f())`

Comment: If it's true, so I don't need to use callback function? If I delete all related callback, the result is same(correct result). then why people use callback?

Comment: @Juntae Callbacks are usually used, when the function performs some async task. The callback is then executed after that task has been completed.

Answer (score 2):

Do don't pass the callback link, but the result of the execution of `second()`. Your code could be written as:

```
var a = second(third);
first( a );
```

This should make it clearer, what happens: You first execute `second()` and pass the result (which is `undefined`) as a "callback" to `first()`.

---

Besides, there are a few syntax errors in this code, it probably should read like this:

```
function first(callback){
    console.log("First");
    callback();
}

function second(callback){
    console.log("Second");
    callback();
}

function third(callback){
    console.log("Third");
}
```

With your code, the callback never would get executed.

Comment: @Juntae you read the first explanation and the other answer about WHY your code does, what it does?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Thanks.!!

Answer (score 1):

As kajyr said, if an argument in a function call has the `()` (which tells the function to execute), it will execute before the other function is actually called.

To see this behavior, you can step through the script using 'step in' in your javascript console. [Treehouse did a decent post on using the js console.](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/mastering-developer-tools-console)

**[And here is a good explanation on stepping over, into, etc.](http://fourkitchens.com/blog/article/step-step-through-debugging)**

I tweaked your code a bit, not sure if this will work for you, but this will give you the proper order. I just make first accept two callbacks and called them in order.

Also, you need the `()` after the var name to execute the methods. IE: `callback();`

```
function first(callback, cb){
    console.log("First");
    callback();
    cb();
}

function second(callback){
    console.log("Second");
}


function third(callback){
    console.log("Third");
}

// Let's run it!

first(second, third);
```

Again, kajyr has a correct answer, I'm just giving another solution, and pointing you in the direction you need to **see** how it works on your own.

Answer (score 0):

If for whatever reason you can't / don't want to switch to promises, the below will work.

```js
// -------------------------------------------------------------- //

function f1(callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('f1 complete');
    callback(null);
  }, 500);
}

const f2 = (callback) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('f2 complete');
    callback(null);
  }, 300);
};

// -------------------------------------------------------------- //

class RunInOrder {
  constructor(functionArray = [], onComplete = () => {}) {
    this._index = 0;
    this._functionArray = functionArray;
    this._onComplete = onComplete;
    this._runNext();
  }

  _runNext() {
    if (this._index >= this._functionArray.length) {
      return this._onComplete();
    }

    const index = this._index++;
    const fn = this._functionArray[index];
    fn((error) => {
      error && console.error(`[f${index}]`, error);
      this._runNext();
    });
  }
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------- //

new RunInOrder(
  [ f1, f2 ],
  () => console.log('All done.'),
);
// ^^ the above outputs:
// f1 complete
// f2 complete
// All done.
```