# Set order to functions in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have 2 functions inside componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.m1();
    this.m2();
}
```

m1 downloads a file I use in m2 but when I run the app I get an error because m2 runs before m1.

Is there a way set the order I want so m1 downloads the file first and then run m2?

Comment: There are plenty of ways, it will depend on how clean you want your code. Also do you have more functions than m1 and m2?

Comment: Yes, 1 more, 3 in total right now

Comment: Sorry, I was afk. You can see these examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556674/how-to-set-function-execute-order-to-using-callback-function-in-javascript choose which will be most clean and beneficial to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some cases those functions could be more efficient and readable if you use promises. Promises help you preventing all that "callback hell" and in the future you would be able to understand all the functionality of any asynchronous and nested function in a easiest way.

for example (you should call the code a copule of times to see an Error or a Success)

```js
const myAsyncFuntion = () => {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    //Some Logic for example a random number betweeen 1 and 10.
    //randomNumber should be smaller than 5. if not, the mySyncFuntion wont be called
    var myRandomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    setTimeout(() =>{      
      if(myRandomNumber <= 5){
        console.log('AsyncFunction with randomNumber = ' + myRandomNumber)
        resolve(myRandomNumber);
      }else{
        console.log('AsyncFunction, with randomNumber = ' + myRandomNumber)
        reject(new Error('randomNumber ' + myRandomNumber + ' is bigger than 5'))
      }
    }, 1000)
  })
};

const mySyncFunction = (number) => {
  //Some Logic
    console.log('SyncFunction, randomNumber as param =>' + number)
};


//MAIN SYNCHRONOUS FUNCTION 
 var consoleLOGS = myAsyncFuntion()
  .then((response) => { //first response from the resolve() method
    mySyncFunction(response)
    return  (response) // you can pass the response to second then() method
  })
  .then((newResponse) => console.log('success, mySyncFunction executed, param recived in 2nd then = ' + newResponse))
  .catch((error) => console.log('error, mySyncFunction wasnt executed, ' + error.message))
```

Note that although the asynchronous function takes 1000ms to be executed, it runs first than the main functionality of the synchronous function `console.log()`, that takes less time. Dont forget that in the `componentDidMount()` method you should call...

```
myAsyncFuntion()
 .then((response) => { 
     mySyncFunction(response)
     return  (response) // you can pass the response to second then() method
   })
 .then((newResponse) => console.log('success... second then = ' + newResponse))
 .catch((error) => console.log('error catched, ...' + error.message))
```

Finally the definition of the functions should be written without the type `const` if they are defined on your main Component. callbacks are pretty good but Promises are better and more readable. Im sure you could do more Logic and implementations with Promises.

If you are working with API requests, you could use axios or fetch. maybe you are using firebase as database and many functions are THENABLE, what means you can access to then and catch methods, because there are Promises returned from the Server.

take a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 0):

You can always use callbacks like

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.m1(params, function(){
        this.m2();
    });
}

function: m1(params, callback) {
    ...
    ...
    callback();
}
```

Comment: I keep getting an error on this line-> function: m1(params, callback). Error: bundling: SyntaxError: .../home.js: Unexpected token, expected ;